# Remove array items with Array.FindAll

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

How can I remove an item in an array?

This is what I have, which is not OK.

```
// fr_watchdog.items = public array
string numToRemove = "test";
fr_watchdog.items = Array.FindAll(fr_watchdog.items,
                                  val => val != numToRemove).ToArray();
```

All done.
I have found a solution for this problem (listed below). Is it possible to delete the question?

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();

int index = Array.IndexOf(items, "Delete me");

if ( index != -1 )
{
    string[] copyStrArr = new string[items.Length - 1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++ )
    {
         copyStrArr[ i ] = items[ i ];
    }
    for ( int i = index ; i < copyStrArr.Length; i++ )
    {
         copyStrArr[ i ] = items[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: “which not OK” does not tell us enough about your problem. What’s the error message and/or the undesired behaviour?

Comment: +1 for Timwi's comment. You (Power-Mosfet) should read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Your edited code only takes count of a single unwanted value. It's also rather more code than calling `FindAll`... and you *still* haven't explained what's wrong with using `FindAll` to start with. You should also look at the `Array.Copy` methods rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "remove" an item from an array really - you can set an element's value to null (assuming it's a reference type) but arrays have a fixed size, so you can't "remove" an element any more than you can "add" one.

What you've shown in your question would create a new array - although it *actually* creates two arrays, because you're calling `ToArray` on the result, for no particular reason.

It's not even clear which `ToArray` method you're calling, given that you mentioned .NET 2, which doesn't include LINQ to Objects. Are you using LINQBridge? The more idiomatic LINQ way would be:

```
fr_watchdog.items = fr_watchdog.items.Where(val => val != numToRemove)
                                     .ToArray();
```

However, you've said that that's "not ok" without saying in what *way* it's not okay. It will create a new array populated with items where the value isn't that of `numToRemove`. In what way is that not what you want?

If the problem is just that the `ToArray` method doesn't work precisely *because* you're using .NET 2 without LINQBridge, then just remove the call to `ToArray()` from your original `FindAll` code. Again, note that that won't change the contents of the *existing* array - so any other references to that original array will still see all the original items.

Comment: LINQ get back-ported to 2.0? :)

Comment: Well, that doesn’t explain why his code doesn’t work, although of course it would have been nice if he had said a bit more about the error.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yes, with LINQBridge. @Timwi: Precisely why I asked for more details, but also explained a few extra things along the way. If the problem is really just that he's trying to use LINQ's `ToArray` method, the simplest fix is to get rid of the call :)

Comment: @Power-Mosfet: So get rid of the call to `ToArray()`, as specified in the last paragraph of my answer. That would have been in my original answer if your question had been more specific, by the way.

Comment: @Jon - Hah I was joking, but haven't looked at at 2.0 stuff at all, all current projects are on 4.0.  Nice to know there's some functionality available if a 2.0 project ever comes across my desk again  :)

Comment: @Nick: Another thing worth knowing is that most of the C# 3 features still work when you're targeting .NET 2. So you can still use lambda expressions, anonymous types, automatically implemented properties and even LINQ query syntax without targeting .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Jon - Excellent point - I suppose my point of view's a bit skewed, I'm using Linq2SQL/Oracle that's not supported the same way without the 3.5 libraries...I don't even think about most of the fundamental linq behaviors/features being available just via the compiler, definitely will now though.

Answer (score 0):

`fr_watchdog.items` could be a read-only *property* (a property without a setter) or a read-only *field* (a field declared with the `readonly` keyword). If that is the case, you cannot assign to it.